# Loading more than one detail view from didselectrowatindexpath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a table view, with just basically 2 rows, add category and delete category. On selection of lets say add category i want to load an add category view, and similar for the delete category. How would i go about doing this, cos an if statement doesn't help.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *selectedCategory = [functionName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 
KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (KeyCryptAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (selectedCategory = @"Add Category")
{

    addCategoryView = [[AddCategoryView alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddCategoryView" bundle:nil]; 
    [appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:addCategoryView animated:YES];

}
if (selectedCategory = @"Delete Category")
{
    deleteCategoryView = [[DeleteCategoryView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DeleteCategoryView" bundle:nil]; 
    [appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:deleteCategoryView animated:YES]; 
}}
```

This code would make add category view appear in both detail views instead of the right one.
Please advise!

Thanks!

---

[EDIT]

### Hey guys thanks for all your answers in a relatively short amount of time! Really appreciate it.

Comment: The answer to your question is below. Also important to note that when you do `(selectedCategory = @"Add category")` you are actually assigning the string `"Add category"` to the variable `selectedCategory`. The comparison operator is `==` (double equals).

Comment: Rog is correct == is used as compare operator here == is use to compare objects not the text.And isEqual: method is use for comparing objects reference.

Comment: accept one of the following answer if you get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this code to

```
if ([selectedCategory isEqualTo:@"Add Category"])
{

    addCategoryView = [[AddCategoryView alloc]initWithNibName:@"AddCategoryView" bundle:nil]; 
    [appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:addCategoryView animated:YES];

}
else if([selectedCategory isEqualTo:@"Delete Category"])
{
    deleteCategoryView = [[DeleteCategoryView alloc]initWithNibName:@"DeleteCategoryView" bundle:nil]; 
    [appDelegate.categoryNavController pushViewController:deleteCategoryView animated:YES]; 
}}
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly work as it says -isEqualto may not respond to NSString. What variable types does isEqual apply to? In any case i used the correct "==" comparison, and that works.

Comment: yes, use isEqualTo not isEqulato. and isEqual apply for comparing references of objects(any kind).

Answer (score 1):

Your way of comparison is wrong .

```
if ([selectedCategory isEqualToString:@"Add Category"])
```

All the best.